# Has the Hulk ever refused to do this in comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, the Hulk

> refused to come out after he was sent back to Earth. Even when his life is threatened he wouldn't come out.

We can only speculate as to the reasons and wait for sequel to come out; but has this ever happened in the comics? If yes, what was the reason?

Comment: FWIW, this could have been easily asked spoiler-free by simply not saying why you were asking.

Comment: @Paul The information is helpful as it provides context to the question in my opinion. Also it makes it clear that they don't want to have answers from the MCU.

Comment: I removed the MCU tag since it's clear you don't want answers from the MCU.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## **No.**

As far as I can tell, the Hulk has never argued with Banner and refused control of his body.

However, the Hulk *has* done the exact opposite: argued with Banner and [demanded](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/hulk/4005-2267/) control of his body, and soon afterward spent several months [suppressing Banner entirely](https://comicbookrealm.com/report/character/13/grey-hulk-mr-joe-fixit-doctor-robert-bruce-banner) and staying in (grey) Hulk form, under the guise of mob strongman Joe Fixit.

[image: Joe Fixit]

Comment: Only in Marvel can a hulking gray-skinned guy pass off as a normal person.

Comment: Heh... hulking.